# Fastest way of sorting NSArray with NSDate Object

Tags: ios, sorting

I have a array which consists of `NSDate` objects.I am able to sort the list successfully but the my sorting operation takes a long time. Upon using the time profile instruments i am able to figure out that `sortUsingDescriptor` takes up more time.

Here's my code:

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
dateForm= [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

[dateForm setDateFormat:@"dd/MM"];
NSSortDescriptor *desc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"eventDate" ascending:NO comparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {

    if(!obj1 || !obj2)
    {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    }

    NSString *todayString = [dateForm stringFromDate:currentDate];
    NSDate *compareDate = [dateForm dateFromString:todayString];
    NSString *date1String = [dateForm stringFromDate:obj1];
    NSString *date2String = [dateForm stringFromDate:obj2];
    NSDate *date1 = [dateForm dateFromString:date1String];
    NSDate *date2 = [dateForm dateFromString:date2String];

    if([date1 compare:compareDate]==NSOrderedAscending)
    {
        date1  = [date1 dateByAddingTimeInterval:365*24*60*60];
    }
    if([date2 compare:compareDate]==NSOrderedAscending)
    {
        date2  = [date2 dateByAddingTimeInterval:365*24*60*60];
    }
    return [date2 compare:date1];
}];

NSArray *tempArray;
tempArray=[self.theMainArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:desc]];

self.theMainArray=[tempArray mutableCopy];

NSLog(@"sort done");
```

How do i sort it faster? 
Thanks

Comment: Ignoring the code for a moment, how do you wish to sort the dates? You are sorting your objects based on the `NSDate` in the `eventData` property. But what is the sort criteria? Is it just on the day and month of the dates?

Comment: @rmaddy i want to sort the dates according to currentDate,if the eventDate is less than the currentDate,then i add it to the next year.In brief,i want to get the latest event first

Comment: But you strip out the year for the comparisons (actually the year gets reset to some default year). And you don't add 1 year, you add a number of seconds that are a bit less than 1 year. Why do you strip the year from the dates and do all of the date/string/date conversions?

Comment: I am stripping the year because,when i retrieve the dates from the web-service that i am calling,i happen to get sometimes the dd-mm,and sometimes dd-mm-yyyy.So to keep it balanced i do this.

Comment: OK. It would be faster to use `NSDateComponents` and extract the day and month from each date. Then compare those (int) values. This also eliminates the need to add a year. Also, don't reprocess `currentDate` over and over like you do. It doesn't change so get its day and month once outside the block.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks i will try,by any chance can i try sorting in this way the db.I am using fmdb in my app